# How to do Ajax login with Spring Security on Grails and AngularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring, grails, spring-security

I'm trying to create user form that sends Ajax request to server to log in.

My `POST` function from Angular looks like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/j_spring_security_check',
    data: {j_username: credentials.username, j_password: credentials.password},
    params: {ajax: true}
})
    .then(function (data) {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        callback && callback();
    },
    function (error) {
        $log.error("Error in login! " + JSON.stringify(error));
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        callback && callback();
    });
```

In `application.yml` I got this configuration for Spring Security:

```
grails:
  plugin:
    springsecurity:
      userLookup:
        userDomainClassName: xxx.LoginUser
      rejectIfNoRule: true
      fii:
        rejectPublicInvocations: false
      controllerAnnotations:
        staticRules:
          [...]
```

Problem occurs when I invoke my function and request is send to the server. Spring Security does not accept mu `j_username` and `j_password` and alway return response with status `200` and error text `{"error":"Sorry, we were not able to find a user with that username and password."}`

PS 
I'm using Spring Security plugin for Grails (3.0.4) http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/guide/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here is the problem. The Spring Security plugin only accepts `POST` request with data as query string and when we pass some data in POST request via Angular's `$http` call, it sends data in request payload body which breaks login and you are getting the message that no user found.

So the first approach is to pass your `username` and `password` as `params` using `$http`:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/j_spring_security_check',
    params: {j_username: credentials.username, j_password: credentials.password, ajax: true}
})
```

The above approach will work fine, but the problem is that the username and password will be sent in the query string so anyone can easily read in the browser console since it is not protected. Also, since that will be passed as query string parameter the password will get logged at various levels like Tomcat's localhost log or Nginx log.

To fix this problem change your code as following:

```
var data = 'j_username=' + credentials.username + '&j_password=' + credentials.password;

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '@/j_spring_security_check',
    data: data,
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
})
```

So what we are doing here is sending the credentials as post data and programmatically changing the `Content-Type` so that Angular can send it as post data instead of as JSON.

*Note*: An additional suggestion: A Grails `request` attribute `request.xhr` will not tell you that your request via Angular is an AJAX request because Angular does not send any request header to make it work like AJAX for Grails. So add the following code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);             // Or whatever your app name is

myApp.run(['$http', function ($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common['x-requested-with'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

Now you don't have to pass `ajax: true` in your Angular `$http` call.

Comment: Thanks for the note about the xhr attribute, I was investigating exactly that. Good to know it is expected behaviour, I'll add the header so I can make Grails differentiate each type of request :)